# Wrong float formatting in PHP (sprintf, printf)

Tags: php, floating-point, printf

I was debugging PHP code and found out the following:

```
$a = 111749392891;

printf('%f', $a);
111749392890.:00000

printf('%F', $a);
111749392890.:00000

printf('%F.2', $a)
111749392890.:00000.2

printf('%F0.2', $a);
111749392890.:000000.2

number_format($a, 2, '.','');
111749392891.00
```

Only number_format() output looks OK to me. Am I missing something? I'm using PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 13):

You are placing the format type modifiers after the format type specifier instead of before. Try this:

```
printf('%.2F', $a)
```

As for the odd output, it is possible that your localization settings are doing that. Try running the line below and see what is returned for your local.

```
echo setlocale(LC_ALL, null);
```

Try changing your locale to something different to see if the problem goes away. Like so:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_CA.UTF-8');
```

Comment: This works, thanks. but what about empty format type modifiers? Does this make sense -> 111749392890.:0000019 ?

Comment: Updated my answer, I can't be sure if it is the problem, but it is the only thing I can think of.

Comment: my locale is Russian_Russia.1251. changed to en_CA.UTF-8. same result. actually it returns 111749392890.:00000, not 111749392890.:0000019.