# Can you explain inconsistent rounding with sprintf?

Tags: php, printf

I've come across what I feel is inconsistent rounding with PHP's `sprintf()` function. The following code:

```
$n = 691.625;
$s = sprintf("%.2f", $n);
$r = round($n, 2);
print "$n: $s $r\n";

$n = 17.565;
$s = sprintf("%.2f", $n);
$r = round($n, 2);
print "$n: $s $r\n";

$n = 19.875;
$s = sprintf("%.2f", $n);
$r = round($n, 2);
print "$n: $s $r\n";
```

produces the following output:

```
691.625: 691.62 691.63
 17.565:  17.57  17.57
 19.875:  19.88  19.88
```

I expected the following:

```
691.625: 691.63 691.63
 17.565:  17.57  17.57
 19.875:  19.88  19.88
```

The difference is in the second number on the first line. So my question is, why does `sprintf()` round down for the first number and up for the second and third?

I've replicated this under PHP 5.4, 5.5 and 7.0. I've included a comparison with the result of `round()`.

(I thought it might have been the internal floating point representation, but all three appear to be stored correctly.)

Comment: What version of PHP?

Comment: I see this under PHP 5.4 and 5.5.

Comment: In PHP 7 its showing same result.

Comment: I don't have access to PHP 7. Anyone?

Comment: The `mode` argument (3rd one) of [round()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) controls the rounding behaviour. I don't know if `sprintf()` internally uses `round()`, but I'd see if you're getting the same behaviour with `round()`, and then try some different modes (the default mode is sadly not documented).

Comment: You can experiment with PHP 7 here: https://repl.it/languages/php

Comment: @pvg I don't think it's rounding half to even. If it was, wouldn't `17.565` be rounded to `17.56`?

Comment: @AtesGoral If I use `round()` I get `691.63`. I'll update the question.

Comment: @dave yep, I got my modes wrong, how did you test what the representation of the numbers was?

Comment: @pvg By printing $n and viewing it within PHPStorm using a breakpoint. I'm pretty sure I've seen things like 691.6249999999995748 when the FP representation is not exact, but I could be wrong.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27108849/1564959)  answer says that why `round` can offer better results than a function not specifically designed for rounding, we need to consider the limits of the double precision floating point representation.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204963/printing-float-values-with-sprintf, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604696/php-float-calculation-2-decimal-point, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28739818/php-how-to-add-leading-zeros-zero-padding-to-float-via-sprintf, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27884209/php-printf-as-float-precision, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294129/wrong-float-formatting-in-php-sprintf-printf, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14764447/how-does-sprintf4-2f-value-function-in-php. Sure one of those post will explain precision lost

Comment: @dave it seems that one actually does have an exact representation. the the last digit, which is at least mildly amusing.

Comment: It's important to note that sprintf will ROUND floats if it thinks it needs to. For example, take the division 31 / 53 = 0.584905[...] - if we want 3 decimal places, we can do sprintf("%.3f", (31 / 53)) but this does NOT give us 0.584. It gives us 0.585

Comment: This one could be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27107238/why-does-phps-sprintf-not-round-5s-reliably

Comment: It seems like sprintf %f rounding (in the rare cases you get an exact number) employs whatever rounding rule the implementors picked. Take a look at https://pastebin.com/4njJzKtd and run it, the rounding on the two exactly represented values suggests an even/odd rounding rule in use. All the other numbers are 'just' rounded if you take into account their full precision. The key thing is probably 'don't rely on sprintf for consistent rounding'

Comment: need php 4.3.0 - 5.2.0 https://3v4l.org/YkSGn